How to use dotnet format to apply IDE0300 on my entire solution?
I am trying to apply Use collection expression for array (IDE0300) suggestion.
I tried to execute the following:
dotnet format ProjectName.sln --diagnostics IDE0300

and also
dotnet format ProjectName.sln --diagnostics IDE0300 --severity info

But the files are not being updated.
How can I correctly apply the IDE0300 diagnostics using dotnet format?

Have you tried adding a rule for IDE0300 to an .editorconfig?  I suspect --diagnostics might only allow you to apply a specific set of rules that are already in your editorconfig.

^^^. Specifically, have you set the dotnet_style_prefer_collection_expression option, so the format command knows what changes you actually want it to make?

Yes I have the following options in .editorconfig dotnet_diagnostic.IDE0300.severity = warning dotnet_style_prefer_collection_expression = true still won't update.

You could try the following steps to correctly apply the IDE0300 diagnostics using dotnet format.
First, please create a .net 8.0 console app and add the following code in the main method.
int[] i = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };
IEnumerable<int> j = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };

Second, please add an empty EditCongfig file to your console app and add the following content.
[*.{cs,vb}]
dotnet_diagnostic.IDE0300.severity = warning
dotnet_style_prefer_collection_expression = true

Third, please choose Tools->Command line->Developer Command Prompt and enter the following command
dotnet format yoursolution.sln --diagnostics IDE0300 --fix-style --verbosity detailed

Finally, you will get the following result:

We find that int[] i = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 }; has changed into  int[] i = [1, 2, 3];.
However, you find that IEnumerable<int> j = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 }; is not changed because the Microsoft describes that when_types_loosely_match is adapted for .NET 9 and later versions.
link


Update dotnet-format:

    dotnet tool install -g dotnet-format
    dotnet tool update -g dotnet-format


Update .editorconfig:

    [*.cs]
    dotnet_diagnostic.IDE0300.severity = suggestion


Run dotnet-format:

    dotnet format ProjectName.sln --diagnostics IDE0300 --fix-style

If files aren't being updated, check the output for any errors.


Resources:
dotnet-format Documentation
EditorConfig Documentation

I did your suggestion. The command ran with no errors. But no files were touched.
